# Adding new Namespace in C# Project

Tags: c#, namespaces, project, addition

I want to add a new namespace to C# project, also number of classes are to be added in that newly created namespace.

When I right-click Solution of Project, I didn't find any link to add a new namespace, similarly by right-clicking Project-Named namespace also.

- How to add a new namespace to existing project?
- Is it necessary to have a class with Main Method in each namespace?
- The project name should be same as namespace name, then how to add
  new in same project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before answer each of the questions, I wanted to shared this from **MSDN**:

> The [`namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) keyword is used to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects. You can use a namespace to organize code elements and to create globally unique types.

**Question 1**

> How to add a new namespace to existing project?

When you create a class you can place it in nearly any namespace you'd like, it can be made up entirely or one that already exists.

```
namespace Something.That.No.One.Else.Has
{
    public class FooBar() { }
}
```

Now, this `Something.That.No.One.Else.Has` namespace is available throughout my application. And I need to use the `using` statement in order to consume the `FooBar` class, unless the consuming class is in the same namespace.

**Question 2**

> Is it necessary to have a class with Main Method in each namespace?

No, there is no requirement built into the language that would impose this. You're probably thinking of `static void Main` for `.exe`.

**Question 3**

> The project name should be same as namespace name, then how to add new in same project?

As I mentioned in *answer 1*, you can simply create a `namespace` as you see fit. I would suggest that for organizational reasons to start a new project though as it will likely be confusing for anyone who starts working in your source.

When you create a new project the naming convention followed is to set the default namespace of the project to the name of the project.

**Update**

After hearing from the OP, I think I have a better understanding of the dilemma.

In your project you should create a folder structure that is relevant to the relationship of the files and their respective implementations. Following recommended [*practices and patterns*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx) from **Microsoft**.

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]

.
+-- Graphs
|   +-- SomeGraphClass.cs // in CompanyName.Product.Graphs namespace
|   +-- ...
+-- Data
|   +-- SomeDataClass.cs  // in CompanyName.Product.Data namespace
|   +-- ...
+-- Interfaces
|   +-- IFooBar.cs        // in CompanyName.Product.Interfaces namespace
|   +-- ...
```

**Update 2**

The folder structure (by default) dictates the `namespace` of the class. For example, when you right-click on the folder and `Add > New Item > Class` - it will create a class in that folder but it will give it the `namespace` as described.

Comment: @David--as I want to put some of my project classes separate as these are related to graph implementation, so where and how to put these classes? Not in separate namespace ?

Comment: I'll update my answer a little as I think I understand a little better the dilemma you're in.

Comment: @David--as you suggested in your update, to put graph related implementations in `CompanyName.Product.Graphs` namespace, so will `Graphs` be a folder or namespace? That is what I asked that how can I add a new namespace in same project?

Comment: @David--right its mean that namespace will remain same, actually I have to create different folders for relevancy to the relationship of the files and their respective implementations and then add required classes and interfaces in those respective folders. Right!

Comment: @David--Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

- How to add a new namespace to existing project?
  *Just add a new folder to your project in which you will put the new classes. The folder name is then part of the namespace: [projectname].[foldername]*
- Is it necessary to have a class with Main Method in each namespace? *Nope, not at all.*
- The project name should be same as namespace name, then how to add new in same project? *By default, the project name is the first part of the namespace. Folders are also part of the namespace, like so: [projectname].[foldername].[subfoldername].[etc]*

Note, you can always overwrite a namespace for your classes by just overriding the default generated namespace:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
    public class FooBar
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZiNNED--if we add 4 classes in that newly added folder where each of 4 classes have to implement an `interface` then where to define that interface? In each class, to define same `interface`?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the interface. As long as you reference it within the classes you're using it in. The interface could exist in its own namespace or folder, for example `[projectname].interfaces`. Then in your classes you reference that namespace in the `using` section, like so: `using [projectname].interfaces;`.

Comment: @ZiNNED--if we create a separate folder for interfaces as you suggested, then do we have to define a class first in that "interfaces" folder and then in that class, an interface should be defined OR can we directly define an interface in that folder ?

Comment: You can directly add an interface by right clicking the folder, selecting `Add` -> `New Item...` and then selecting `Visual C#` -> `Code` and selecting the `Interface` type.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have just encountered a situation like this in my WPF project. Maybe, this not the exact title for my situation but when I searched it, I could not find any proper solutions for it. Hope it helps others,

Long story short;

I have created a new C# project under my 'Solution'. And I just wanted to use one of the class definitions that was included by the new project. However, even if I add the following snippet to my .xaml code, I was not able to use the 'Path'.

```
xmlns:Path="clr-namespace:namespace;assembly=namespace"
```

So what I did was just nothing else but just adding the project as a reference to my Leading project.