# Global using directive in c#

Tags: c#, using

I'd like to create a namespace in c# that can be found in any project. Not just the one that it is located in. like the system namespace. Is that possible and if yes I'd like to know how.
I already googled and didn't find anything

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026278/adding-new-namespace-in-c-sharp-project

Comment: "I'd like to create a namespace in c#" - did you solve this step or do you need help here? "that can be found in any project ...  like the system namespace" - that's not possible. Someone needs a reference to your DLL.

Comment: Which .NET version, which IDE?

Comment: This is a really bad idea, but has to be learned in the School of Hard Knocks.  Set laser to  stun and add the classes to the global namespace.  In other words, no `namespace` declaration in the source file.

Comment: @HansPassant: That will make the classes available _within_ the given project, but won't inherently make them available for "any project." Since the OP specifically calls out the `System` namespace as an example of what they're trying to accomplish, I don't think a global namespace is truly what they have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in the `System` namespace are part of the Base Class Library (BCL) that gets included as part of the .NET Runtime. The only way for you to have your class be as globally accessible as, say, the `System.String` class, would be to convince Microsoft to add your class into their BCL. That is rare, but not unheard of. The `IObservable<>` interface is an example of a type that was added that way.

However, there are tons of classes that people are using every day without having them added to the BCL. If you're willing to accept one additional step for people to take with their projects, in order to leverage your project, you can [publish your project's output as a Nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package). Then people only need to add your Nuget package (referenced by its package name), and they'll have access to the public API defined by the types in your DLLs.

Consumers of your package will still need to reference the namespaces of the types they want to use, either explicitly or via a [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive). In C#, a "global using directive" only makes the namespace globally available within the project that the directive is found in.

If you only want your types to be accessible from other projects found in the same solution, Nuget isn't necessary: you can add a [project reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022).

There are a lot of nuances I'm glossing over (i.e. differences between namespaces and DLLs and packages), but which it would be helpful for you to read about.

Answer (score -1):

One of solution:
You need to create library(DLL) and refernce it in projects.
If you using visual studio 201x you can create project with type class library.
The library namespaces can be found use like this ´using MyNamespace;´

example of class in library:
[image: example of class in library]

adding refernce to project:
[image: adding refernce to project]

example of using your own class library:

[image: example of using your own class library]